# XmlWriter and a "custom" root element

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have to generate an XML document from a Class and have it conform to the submission requirements of a RESTful api. Their structure dictates a couple of structures in the root element of the XML being sent to them for processing, and I'm unable to mimic their requirements in my current coding efforts.

I've looking at using decorations on the class itself [XmlRoot()] and XmlSerializerNamespaces in the code, and neither approach yields the required results.

The root element needs to look like the following:

```
<tns1:RatingRequest xmlns:tns="http://schemas.blah.com/blah/v1/blah/blah" xmlns:tns1="http://schemas.blah.com/blah/blah/blah/blah" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.blah.com/blah/v1/blah/blah blah.xsd ">
```

When I used the XmlSerializerNamespaces to add the 'tns1' prefix, it prefixed every element in the XmlDocument, not just the root element.

When I use the XmlRoot decoration in the class, it doesn't seem to support all of the necessary items, specifically the xsi and xsi:schemaLocation.

To make matters worse, it seems like tns and tns1 are redundant as I can't find any sort of documentation to explain the difference between the two or confirming the redundancy.

Could someone please help me get back on the proper track to construct the root element to conform to the requirements above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share `blah.xsd`, at least show us whether it has `elementFormDefault="qualified"` or `unqualified`. The `XmlElementAttribute` has a corresponding property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx you should use for your elements. It doesn't really make much sense to solely post the root element markup, we need to see some contents as well.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion @MartinHonnen, however, I'm not sure the licensing agreement will permit me to post it.I did look into the xsd and found the following included in the xs:schema node: `elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"`

Comment: I would use the `xsd.exe` command line tool on the schema to generate C# classes matching the schema, then you can use the generated classes or at least see how to use the attributes on your classes.

Comment: Umm...yeah, @MartinHonnen. We tried that, too...there's so many includes in the .xsd and in-document properties being built the `xsd.exe` rolled over on its back and begged for mercy. It couldn't complete one of the .xsd's...and we tried to pick the least complex one to start with. Like I said earlier, we're not dealing with really good source material.